# Cloudformation Output of Cloudformation Init

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, devops, infrastructure-as-code

I have got a CloudFormation stack , shown as below ,

```
  "Metadata" : {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
                "config" : {

                        "/home/ec2-user/create_db_user.sh" : {
                            "source" :                             

   "http://s3.amazonaws.com/devops/create_db_user.sh",
                            "mode" : "000755",
                            "owner" : "ec2-user"
                        }
                    }
 ...
```

I need to run this command when EC2 instance is up , after i need set this init script output to the cloudformation stack .

How I can to this .

Comment: What do you mean by having the output in CloudFormation? Do you want to know if it was successful or do you want to see `stdout`?

Comment: Are you looking for deploying user-data using cloudformation template? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Comment: @kichik I want to see the stdout at the AWS cloudformation console in stack outputs

Comment: How big of an output are we talking?

Comment: I'm running a script for create random username and password i need to show it output

Comment: perhaps if you tell us what the use case is we could help, trying to get the o/p of the script inside ec2 to cloudformation, why not try to use AWS Secrets manager for DB users and password? Also, you can have a lambda function as well to create random users and passwords ,store them in AWS Secrets manager pass back the data you want via response data to cloudformation

Answer (score 10):

A bit late to the party but in addition to the previous answer...

The output of `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` at EC2 instance creation is not accessible through Cloudformation.

However on the EC2 instances that have been started you will find logs for both `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` (aka. `cfn-init`) and from user-data (`cloud-init`).

On Amazon Linux this is structured as follows:

- /var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log: cfn-init and command output with timestamps
- /var/log/cfn-init.log: cfn-init and command output
- /var/log/cloud-init.log: cloud init logs pertaining to running the commands in user-data
- /var/log/cloud-init-output.log: output from the user-data commands themselves

The simplest way to access those logs is to stream the logs to Cloudwatch Logs, which will enable you to search and filter the logs by time and content. Also consider using Cloudwatch Insights for search and filtering - it's got a more comprehensive and understandable syntax for search, filter and even simple visualisation (chart).

Seeing as you're already using cfn-init, you can find information [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent-New-Instances-CloudFormation.html) on how to install the new'ish Cloudwatch Agent (not Cloudwatch Logs Agent!). The benefit of using the Cloudwatch Agent is that it can also stream custom metrics to Cloudwatch Metrics (e.g. memory usage, app metrics, database metrics etc).

For already running EC2 instances, consider having a look at `cfn-hup` [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-hup.html).

The alternative would be to use SSM (Systems Manager) to push out the Agent onto already running instances as per instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/download-CloudWatch-Agent-on-EC2-Instance-SSM-first.html).

Answer (score 3):

In comments to your question there are some valid points to push you towards correct solution. In general what you try to do is impossible - there are no outputs of `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` resource. They are not evaluated at stack creation time, just stored and processed by EC2 instance on it's launch time, but it's not the time CloudFormation stack is running (may be, but not always - take auto scaling group for example).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html#outputs-section-structure-output-fields) doc - The value of an output can include literals, parameter references, pseudo-parameters, a mapping value, or intrinsic functions.

Given that, `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` is a CloudFromation Metadata specific type but not a literal, parameter, pseudo-parameter, mapping value, or intrinsic function.

So, what you are trying to achieve is appearing to be as a CloudFormation Outputs limitation :(

[@m-jensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684005/m-jensen) answer lists many suitable workarounds for this.